# How to connect subnet on second NIC to internet

Tags: networking, linux-networking, subnet, nic, gateway

I tried googling for a while, but I can't put my problem to a good search query so I can't find an answer for what I'm trying to do.

Here we go:
I have 3 PCs that I'm trying to connect with my own subnet. One of them is already connected to an outside network and has internet connection.
Here's my configuration:

- PC1: has two NICs,

  - eth0 has the DHCP IP 192.168.0.11, the gateway is 192.168.0.1, and DNS is set automatically to 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 1.0.0.1, 4.4.4.4. This is the outside network.
  - eth1 has the static IP 192.168.70.1, I set the gateway to 192.168.0.11 (the IP of eth0), I didn't set DNS.
- PC2: has the static IP 192.168.70.2. Gateway is 192.168.70.1. No DNS.
- PC3: has the static IP 192.168.70.2. Gateway is 192.168.70.1. No DNS.

Now the two networks work beautifully. I can ssh, ping, and whatever else I need to do except for internet. So my question is the following:

1. How do I set the gateway on PC1-eth1 so it forwards from the inner network to the outer one? my current solution doesn't work.
2. How do I set the DNS for PC1-eth1, PC2, and PC3? do I simply set it to 8.8.8.8 and the gateway will handle the DNS requests? Or do I have to setup a DNS server?!

All three machines are using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tiring search. I found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29

Which describes how to do this type of forwarding between different networks through two NICs. Exactly what I'm looking for.